# vagrant share with laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I'm running into an issue getting vagrant share to work in conjunction with the laravel homestead vagrant box. My homestead.yaml file looks like:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/Projects/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel

sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

When I hit http://laravel.app:8000 - everything works fine. When I start up `vagrant share` the URL that's generated returns the error `No input file specified.`

I'm stumped. Searching Google for hours hasn't resulted in a solution. I'm sure it's just some basic configuration thing and I'm not connecting the dots. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There's a solution without having to do anything on your homestead VM.

You can install a program called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which does a similar thing to `vagrant share` but works better with the multiple sites that Homestead uses. You will need to sign up for an account but basic usage is free.

Run: `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite your-local-site.app:80`

(Where your-local-site.app is what's used for the map directive in your `Homestead.yaml` file)

Then your site will be available globally on the url that ngrok gives you.

Answer (score 7):

@sanaco's answer missed some steps for me. This is full command to create the share (after logging in)

```
vagrant share --http 80 --name silly-sausage
```

On completion the command will out put the share URL which should look like this

```
http://silly-sausage.vagrantshare.com
```

Once the share is up you need to ssh into the vagrant box with

```
 vagrant ssh
```

And run

```
serve silly-sausage.vagrantshare.com ~/Code/project/path/public
```

Without the http flag vagrant assigns 443 to http which makes nginx complain about HTTPS port being used for HTTP connection.

By specifying the name you only need to do the serve command first time.

Comment: Mike could you take a look at my question in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108320/vagrant-share-and-laravel-homestead

Comment: @padawanTony use Ngrok with the `--host-header` set to the name of your laravel app eg `myproject.dev`. its easier to setup and keep working

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. Can you post a complete answer (step-by-step) to my thread? I have never used ngrok before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to create an account for [Vagrant Cloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/account/new), if you haven't already.

Once you've done that, in your terminal (**not** logged into the Homestead machine) run `vagrant login` and login with your details.

Then run `vagrant global-status` to find the ID of the vagrant machine Homestead is running on.

Run `vagrant share 123a4` (where `123a4` is the machine ID) and your machine will be shared!

Note that you might have to set up your Nginx configuration to listen for the URL that has been generated for you so it points to the correct site on the machine.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I've been trying to figure this out for the longest time.

Comment: Can you explain the last paragraph? How do you "listen to the URL"?

Comment: You need to map the URL to the directory on your vagrant machine. So, using Homestead, you can run `serve url-to-vagrant-cloud.com ~/path/to/your/code/public` which will do that for you.

Comment: @Sacha could you take a look at my question in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108320/vagrant-share-laravel-homestead-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in your homestead directory: `vagrant provision`

To get share URL use this command:
`vagrant share`

Sometimes it doesn't worke on windows.
Use
`vagrant share --http 8000`

`8000` is port as `homestead` uses port forwarding `8000 -> 80`

Note: To use vagrant share you must have [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) installed.