# Vagrant Share - Laravel Homestead, Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, homestead, ngrok, vagrant-share

When I run `vagrant share id-goes-here --http 80`, the terminal gets stuck and it does not show me a URL:

```
==> homestead-7: Detecting network information for machine...
    homestead-7: Local machine address: 127.0.0.1
    homestead-7:  
    homestead-7: Note: With the local address (127.0.0.1), Vagrant Share can only
    homestead-7: share any ports you have forwarded. Assign an IP or address to your
    homestead-7: machine to expose all TCP ports. Consult the documentation
    homestead-7: for your provider ('virtualbox') for more information.
    homestead-7:  
    homestead-7: Local HTTP port: 80
    homestead-7: Local HTTPS port: disabled
    homestead-7: Port: 2222
    homestead-7: Port: 27017
    homestead-7: Port: 33060
    homestead-7: Port: 4040
    homestead-7: Port: 44300
    homestead-7: Port: 54320
    homestead-7: Port: 8000
    homestead-7: Port: 8025
==> homestead-7: Creating Vagrant Share session...
```

but when I go to https://dashboard.ngrok.com/status, a URL has been created for me. For example, http://eaeefc3d.ngrok.io

However, when I go to this URL, I get the default Apache welcome page.

I have also tried to ssh into homestead and run the command:
`serve eaeefc3d.ngrok.io ~/Code/myapp/public/` (as I read in Mike Miller's answer in this thread: [vagrant share with laravel homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763218/vagrant-share-with-laravel-homestead)) which gives me the output:

`dos2unix: converting file /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh to Unix format...` but I still get the Apache welcome page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MikeMiller for pointing me in the right direction with his comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763218/vagrant-share-with-laravel-homestead/35114288?noredirect=1#comment97002994_35114288)

#### Here is how I got ngrok to work:

1. ssh into homestead, ie. `homestead up` and `homestead ssh`
2. cd to the project directory, ie. `cd Code/foodonsale/`
3. Run ngrok with the `-host-header` set to the project name:
       ngrok http -host-header=rewrite myproject.test:80
4. You will get an output like the following:
       ngrok by @inconshreveable

   ```
   Session Status         online                                                           
   Session Expires        7 hours, 59 minutes                                               
   Update                 update available (version 2.3.18, Ctrl-U to update)              
   Version                2.2.8                                                            
   Region                 United States (us)                                               
   Web Interface          http://192.168.10.10:4040                                        
   Forwarding             http://0b7f6aa0.ngrok.io -> myproject.test:80                   
   Forwarding             https://0b7f6aa0.ngrok.io -> myproject.test:80
   ```
5. Go to the URL designated by `Web Interface`. Here you can monitor the requests of your application.
6. Click on either the `http` or the `https` options to be redirected to the live public version of yout application.

---

Useful links:
- [ngrok DOC](https://ngrok.com/docs#host-header)